# Javascript - web chat variant. Import of txt log on connection for newly connected user

Tags: javascript

As in the title - i'm looking for/thinking of a javascript code that would import last few lines of a txt file without certain signs (print the last few messages logged on server) - then print them on the chat window that is present on the site, but only for the user that has just connected - something like a flash-back of last few messages for new user to know what was the subject of last talk.

Found nothing that hit the spot, something with XMLHttpRequest and something with FileReader, yet too low on actual JS skill to extract most valuable info.
Tried to write something but it ended as a piece of junk.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript no support Read or Write into a file.
You can use Server-Sent Events: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp
then Write log with Server Side Language

Comment: You think i could try to do the job with PHP ? Thanks for the advice too, it looks much easier and at least is easily explained :P
Task of reading the log is just on connection, so guess it won't be so hard now